# Pardot engagement program

Tags: automation, pardot

I have created a engagement program in pardot. 10 propest enters the program. From Engagement studio - report, I click on '10' mentioned along with 'start'. It shows me those 10 prospects who entered the program with following columns - 'INITIALLY PROCESSED', 'LAST PROCESSED', 'UPDATED' etc. along with other columns. What does these three columns mean?